# Google Maps Flash API: InfoWindow Letterspacing

Tags: flash, google-maps, infowindow

The letterspacing in my Google Maps Flash API infoWindow is a little weird. The letters are very tightly spaced. For example, double "r"s touch and look like an "m". Is there a way to adjust the letterspacing?

```
var infoWindowSettings:InfoWindowOptions = new InfoWindowOptions();
infoWindowSettings.content = theName;
infoWindowSettings.hasShadow = true;
infoWindowSettings.hasCloseButton = true;
infoWindowSettings.width = 200;
map.openInfoWindow(map.getCenter(), infoWindowSettings);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've got. I added the letterspacing property below:

```
var contentFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat("Arial", 13);
    contentFormat.letterSpacing = 1;


var infoWindowSettings:InfoWindowOptions = new InfoWindowOptions({
    strokeStyle: {
     color: 0x000000
    },
    fillStyle: {
      color: 0xFFFFFF,
      alpha: 0.8
    },
    contentFormat: contentFormat,
      width: 280,
      hasCloseButton: true,
      hasTail: true,
      hasShadow: true
    });
```